# could not find function "melt" even though "reshape" is installed and loaded

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I'm running a simple script using the melt function, but I get an

> Error: could not find function "melt"

I have used the function before and it worked fine. The reshape package is installed and loaded. I removed it and reinstalled it, but still it does not work. Even `"reshape" %in% rownames(installed.packages())` is `TRUE`.

Comment: Did you use `library(reshape)` first? It shows up in `sessionInfo()`? By the way, remember use the R tag next time :)

Comment: You might need to use library(reshape2)

Comment: @ Michael: It did not work with reshape2 either.

Comment: @Frank: Yes, I loaded reshape first. However, I loaded several packages at the same time. Now, I load them seperately and the script works. I don't get why, but...

Comment: Hm ok, I don't know why either. I always load separately. Btw, if you put a space after the @, the person is not pinged.